# How to reset Choice chip? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using navigation when the user taps on a selected choice chip, but when the user returns back to the back i see the choice chip is still selected, how to reset it?

```
List<Widget> chips = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      ChoiceChip chip = ChoiceChip(
        label: Text(options[i]),
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.sp.toDouble(), color: Colors.black54, letterSpacing: 1),
        selected: _selectedOptionIndex == i,
        elevation: 10,
        pressElevation: 5,
        shadowColor: Colors.black54,
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(.2),
        selectedColor: ColorConstants.kPrimaryAccent,
        onSelected: (bool selected) {
          setState(() {
            if (selected) {
              _selectedOptionIndex = i;
              if (_selectedOptionIndex == 0) {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => BookingScreen1(fees: widget.fees)));
              } else if (_selectedOptionIndex == 1) {
                print("Parcel");
              } else if (_selectedOptionIndex == 2) {
                print("Speed");
              } else if (_selectedOptionIndex == 3) {
             
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PTScreen()));
              }
            }
          });
        },
      );
```

Comment: Share your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your selection to be true, negate it every time you change your screen.

```dart
if (selected) {
              _selectedOptionIndex = i;
              if (_selectedOptionIndex == 0) {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => BookingScreen1(fees: widget.fees)));
                selected = !selected;
              } else if (_selectedOptionIndex == 1) {
                print("Parcel");
              } else if (_selectedOptionIndex == 2) {
                print("Speed");
              } else if (_selectedOptionIndex == 3) {
             
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PTScreen()));
                selected = !selected;
              }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).